# Creating global macros and templates in jenkins job builder

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-job-builder

I currently have my jenkins job builder directory structure like so:

```
jenkins
    ---global-defaults.yaml
    ---global-macros.yaml
    ---global-templates.yaml
    ---projectfolderA
     | ---projectA.yaml
```

projectA.yaml can find the templates and macros when they are in the projectAfolder, but can't in the current situation. It can always find global-defaults.

Is there any way I can get project.yaml files in sub-directories to recognize top level templates/macros?

Answer (score 0):

When updating jobs, simply append the path to the directory storing global defaults/template/macros.

```
jenkins-jobs --conf config_file update path_to_project_folder:path_to_globals_folder
```